# Adding new attribute on registration page?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on task adding pan attribute on registration page. It got added on storefront. But the problem is data is not getting stored in database as after hitting register tab error coming on console like

> [/grocerymatestorefront] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException: [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.MandatoryAttributesValidator@246420ba]:missing values for [pan] in model CustomerModel () to create a new Customer] with root cause
> de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.MandatoryAttributesValidator$MissingMandatoryAttributesException: [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.MandatoryAttributesValidator@246420ba]:missing values for [pan] in model CustomerModel () to create a new Customer

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: have you add the attribute to its Form object? Also, when you debug it, where did you lose the value? Is it in controller, abstract controller, facade, or service?

Answer (score 2):

`MandatoryAttributesValidator` looks at all properties that have been marked as required in the typesystem (based on the items.xml)

In the items.xml, you should mark the property pan as `optional=true` on the modifiers. Something like this:

```
<attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="pan">
    <persistence type="property" />
    <modifiers optional="true" />
</attribute>
```

Don't forget to run an update system after chaning the items.xml, otherwise this change won't be changed in the database

Comment: are you setting the field in a property? or do you expect some kind of default value? Without customizations, this will save the pan field to the database (if you set it on the object you want to save). Do note that I don't know what your pan object is, so I added the type String for demonstration purpose. if you have a custom object, you need to change the type to that.
If you do all of this, you could also try to first save your pan object, and then the customer object

Comment: as it comes from the registering, this data gets stored in the registrationData object most likely, did you change/add a populator to copy over this field from the data object to the model object? seems to me like you have some populator missing in your code.